# Is the value of the argument passed to the callback of catch method ("error") during axios request boolean?

Tags: reactjs, promise, callback

Am new to react. During axios get request I am confused what the the value of the  argument is in the callback of the catch method. To be clear the following is the snippet of the code I am trying to figure out the concept behind axios requuest.

```
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
          
          .then(responce => {
            console.log(responce)
            this.setState(
              {posts : responce.data}
            )
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error))
          }
```

Comment: you are doin it correctly

Comment: https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors

Comment: `error` is expected to be an error instance. Why are you expecting a boolean?

Comment: If `this.setState()` has been coded correctly to throw an Error object, then your `.catch()` will always be passed an Error object. If `this.setState()` throws something other than an Error object, then your `.catch()` will be passed that other thing. This is the precisely why we should all always throw proper Errors.

Answer (score 0):

The `error` parameter is an object with information about the failed request so that you can appropriately handle it, such as the response code (EG 200, 404, 500), any response data returned by the server and the headers present on the response. The following can be found in the axios [documentation for handling errors](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors):

```js
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .catch(function (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
      // that falls out of the range of 2xx
      console.log(error.response.data);
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.headers);
    } else if (error.request) {
      // The request was made but no response was received
      // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
      // http.ClientRequest in node.js
      console.log(error.request);
    } else {
      // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
      console.log('Error', error.message);
    }
    console.log(error.config);
  });
```

Take note of the comments in the code above, as they explain what the error object contains in different situations resulting from an error while making the request.

If you would like to view more information about the HTTP error, you can use the `toJSON()` method on the error, also in the documentation.

```js
axios.get('/user/12345')
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.toJSON());
  });
```